# How to check every open tabs' url ? And how to do an action to tabs with a matching URL ?"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm completelly new to coding (except some basic VBA and some SQL) and I need to create a chrome extension that will refresh every tabs that contain an URL starting with "https://localhost:4848/sense/app/", and do that every 15 minutes.

From what I've learnt in the past 3 hours, I would say that I need to put it in the background.js file, and make it a persistent file, then use a SetInterval to call the function. Unfortunatelly I basicly have no clue on how to get the different strings, and how to force a refresh on different tabs

I got some code to get the amount of tabs and all there URLs, but it's giving me way too much informations, and I don't know to put a condition for those with matching URL:

```
'

chrome.windows.getAll({populate: true}, function(allWindows)
{console.log(allWindows);
});
```

`

I expect it to refresh every tab with a URL starting with https://localhost:4848/sense/app/

Comment: `chrome.tabs.query({url: 'https://localhost:4848/sense/app/*'}, tabs => { ......... })`

Comment: And so I need to put the code to refresh the tabs in {........} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use [chrome.alarms](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) API, since you have minutes interval. So then you don't need to keep persistent background page.

Your code will be looking like this:

```
chrome.alarms.create('my_alarm', {
    periodInMinutes: 15
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(alarm => {
    if (alarm && alarm.name === 'my_alarm') {
        chrome.tabs.query({url: 'https://localhost:4848/sense/app/*'}, foundTabs => {
            if (foundTabs && foundTabs.length) {
                foundTabs.forEach(tab => chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply, I tried your code by simply putting it in my background file, and I get an error... "Uncuaght TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' or undefined at background.js:1"

Comment: Nevermind, forgot to add the "alarms" permission ! I'll see if it works :)